# How can I align the bottom of two columns in a same page with multicol?

Tags: multicol

I would like to align horizontally the bottom of two columns in a same page in a document with `multicol`. Apparently there is a recurrent minimal difference between the bottom alignment of the columns.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-5]
\par\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean align *vertically*, right? You want both columns to end at the same vertical position? That would imply *balancing*, which [`multicol`](//ctan.org/pkg/multicol) already does...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if I compile your MWE, on screen the left column of the first page seems to be a little bit shorter than the column on the right.

I made a printout. Both columns were exactly aligned.

I made a snapshoot and painted a line above: same result.

[image: blindtext with red line]

So your (and mine as well) observation seems to be an artifact.